# (C Language) prime factorization. How to make output 2 2 2 3 7 7 become 2^3 * 3^1 * 7^2?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n,i;
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for(i=2;i>=n/2;i++)
    {
        
        while(n%i==0)
        {
            printf("%d  ",i);
            n=n/i;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(C Language) prime factorization. How to make output 2  2  2  3  7  7 become 2^3 * 3^1 * 7^2 ?

Comment: Keep a count of each factor instead of printing it right away.  Print the factor and its count (when the count is greater than 0) after you have the full count for that factor, formatted however you like.

Comment: Count the number of times same digit repeat. there is no variable declared which count how many times your numbers are repeating

Comment: Hi Brianna, it would be great if you would add some information on what you already tried to achieve a solution and where you got stuck.

Comment: `i >= n/2` It's unlikely the be the correct condition. In `for` loops the condition must evaluate `true` to execute the body.